# MAGMI - Mass import Magento

Tags: magento, magmi

Can you guys share some pros & cons about Magmi ?

I am evaluating for our Magento 1.12 implementation, Since we are updating feeds frequently also the feed contains huge data.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

I've been using Magmi for almost a year now to perform mass Magento imports for wide client base.

**Pros:**

- Very Fast imports (thousands of products in a matter of seconds)
- Plugin system that allows you to extend the core functionality of Magmi (extremely powerful for custom data imports)
- Surprisingly stable and maintained for the latest versions of Magento

**Cons:**

- <del>Lacks authentication (you'll have to setup some authentication so nobody can access it.  It's pretty easy to do)</del> -

  **[Magmi's latest versions](https://github.com/dweeves/magmi-git) now include an authentication layer that requires a Magento Admin Login to access it's UI.**
- The UI is somewhat unintuitive and ugly (it's by developers for developers.  It wasn't made to look pretty)
- It will make you realize how silly the standard Magento import methods are (lets face it, they're slow)

For your case (updating feeds frequently), Magmi will work just fine.  You can essentially upload a new CSV, and call Magmi either from an HTTP request, or using the included command line functionality.  It's very straightforward to setup and easy to maintain.

Comment: did you tried working with sql datasource? any special guideline to use it? im continually receiving "No Records returned by datasource", thanks for any guideline. I started a question about this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130191/magmi-generic-sql-datasource-1-0-2-usage