# magmi - generic sql datasource 1.0.2 usage

Tags: magmi

Some questions arises when using MAGMI generic SQL datasource. Magmi 0.7.18 displays the following input information when using that plugin:

[image]

I tried several times with two approaches. 
-the first one as described on the image was a direct query to the mysql database containing all rows to feed magento database using magmi. (no files on genericsql/requests)
-the second one using .sql file exported from my database and placing that file into (genericsql/requests).

in both cases I received the following statement: 1 warning(s) found Hide Details -> "No Records returned by datasource"

I read that some folks suggest to use input DB Initial Statement: SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM tablename but in my case it was the same.

question one: using mysql I can query mysql databse directy using the input db information (type, host, name, user, password) or I have to place the sql file in genericsql/requests too? is that my error?

question two: based on the fact that mysql cannot attach files - as MS sql can - which information do I have to place when magmi request user- pass for that sql file?

any help appreciated, I´m stuck with this issue and CSV is not suitable for my needs. brgds

Comment: question was answered here : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/23552/

Answer (score 0):

by dweeves:

Your SELECT has to be put in a .sql file in the directory listed in red. (name it as you want as long as it ends with .sql extension)

The "Initial Statements" is a field that is meant to hold the "connection" time statements (like SET NAMES 'UTF8').

For the "quick count" , you might also add a .sql.count file in the same dir with the same name that the request you want to achieve.

By default magmi will find the count using a

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (your request here)
```

see [Generic SQL Datasource](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/magmi/index.php?title=Import_-_Generic_SQL_Datasource) plugin documentation.